# Uploading multiple large files via a browser and verifying the upload

Tags: browser, upload, verification

I need to allow web users to:

- upload multiple files via a browser
- upload large files (> 2GB)
- verify the upload was not corrupted

I've seen recommendations for Uploadify and Jumploader, however, it isn't clear to me if these applications verify the uploaded file (such as, comparing MD5 of client-side file vs. uploaded). The application must support event hooks prior to and post upload. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be willing to post an update to your question, either in form of an edit to the question or as an answer, indicating what you decided to do? This would perjhaps renew interest in your post and hopefully encourage some feedback from the community.